Cannot use getImageData within content.js [The Canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data]
I am creating a chrome extension that reads all images within a page and runs a deep learning model on them.
  let width = canvas.width;
  let height = canvas.height;
  let startX = (width - size) / 2;
  let startY = (height - size) / 2;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let imageData = ctx.getImageData(startX, startY, size, size);

A lot of the times, I get the following error
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
Is there any other way for getting the imageData?


Add the site or "<all_urls>" to host_permissions in manifest.json, 2) Send src of all images via chrome.runtime.sendMessage. 3) In the background script create the offscreen document with chrome.runtime.onMessage listener which will create a new Image, set its src to each of the urls from the message, load it, then use getImageData and pass it to your library that also runs in the offscreen document.


@wOxxOm The library that will process the image must be running in the background.js? or is it possible to send the imageData back to the content.js script?

In the offscreen document. What is the output of the library?

@wOxxOm Nevermind, can we achieve something similar using screenCapture and getting the x,y,width,height of each img div? because the offscreen solution seems to be complicated and I cannot find any examples.
